# Find all paths between 2 given nodes

Tags: java

I want to find all the paths between 2 nodes, and save them into a list. This is part of a problem where I need to find the shortest path between 2 cities. I have to use BFS so I was thinking to apply a BFS on my graph and save all the paths between the 2 cities in a list.So far I've implemented this but I'm stuck with those cities and routes. I want my list to be a list of `Routes` but I don't know how to do that.

```
public class Route {

    private final City node;
    private final int cost; 

      public Route(City node, int cost) {
        this.node = node;
        this.cost = cost;
      }

      public City getCity() {
        return node;
      }
      public int getCost() {
        return cost;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return "{" + node + ", " + cost + "}";
      }

}

    public class Graph {

    private final List<City> cities;
    private final List<Route> routes;
    private final Map<City, List<Route>> myGraph = new HashMap<City,List<Route>>();
private List<City> visited = new LinkedList<City>();
    private List<City> beenThere = new LinkedList<City>();


      public List<List<City>> BFS(Graph graph, City from, City to) {
          List<List<City>> rute = new ArrayList<List<City>>();
          Queue<City> toVisit = new LinkedList<City>();
          toVisit.add(from);
          beenThere.add(from);
          while(!toVisit.isEmpty()) {
              City node = toVisit.remove();
              visited.add(node);
              Queue<City> neighbors = new LinkedList<City>();
              neighbors = this.getNeighbors(node);
              while(!neighbors.isEmpty()) {
                  visited.add(neighbors.element());
                  checkRoute(neighbors.remove());
              }
              if (beenThere.get(beenThere.size()-1).equals(to))
                  rute.add(beenThere);
              beenThere.clear();
              beenThere.add(from);
          }
          return rute;
      }
```

I have modified the BFS and added a new function. It doesn't work. Could you please help me figure it out what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: Have you tried "something" ?

Comment: Yes I have, for a given graph the BFS finds only a path, I want to find all the paths

Comment: OK, then It's better to share your code, so you can get not only a solution to your problem but also what was wrong with your first approach.

Comment: I have updated the question with all my code

Comment: No one will help me, even if have put the entire code? :(

Comment: you can not expect that all question will be answered in less than an hour, the people that are trying to help are voluntaries that share their time and knowledge for free, so by patient, maybe someone familiar with BFS can take a look.

Comment: Ok I'll keep waiting. I want you to know that I tried a lot, not just come here and paste some code. I really want to understand what is going on there.

Comment: Not read the code 100% so may have missed something, but in the BFS method it looks like your first while loop only continues until (!found) - and you set found=true soon as you find the target city - so you would only ever get one route? (e.g. abort the while loop as soon as you find a route)

Comment: e.g. if you want to find all routes you need to keep searching until all cities have been visited (assuming you dont want any routes that include repeating cities).

Comment: Could you help me with some code please? I deleted the found section but I get the same result..

Comment: If you had created an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (for example, by adding a `main` method that reads the "graph.txt" file that you added and removed by editing the question a few times) it would be *much* easier to help. Apart from that: You are really looking for ALL possible paths between the nodes? (The number of paths will grow exponentially, so this makes only sense for small graphs. Apart from the fact that *cycles* in the paths may obviously not be allowed....)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `KShortestPaths` from JGraphT library.

According to the documentation, this implementation uses Bellman-Ford algorithm:

> The algorithm determines the k shortest simple paths in increasing
>   order of weight. Weights can be negative (but no negative cycle is
>   allowed), and paths can be constrained by a maximum number of edges.
>   Multigraphs are allowed.
>
> The algorithm is a variant of the
>   Bellman-Ford algorithm but instead of only storing the best path it
>   stores the "k" best paths at each pass, yielding a complexity of
>   O(k*n*(m^2)) where m is the number of edges and n is the number of
>   vertices.

It also knows how to deal with cycles in the graph.

A simple example:

```
@Test
public void findAllPaths() {
    DirectedGraph<String, Edge> directedGraph = buildDirectedGraph();

    KShortestPaths<String, Edge> pathInspector = 
                                            new KShortestPaths<String, Edge>(
                                                        directedGraph, 
                                                        "A", 
                                                        Integer.MAX_VALUE, 
                                                        Integer.MAX_VALUE
                                                    );


    List<GraphPath<String, Edge>> paths = pathInspector.getPaths("D");

    assertThat(paths).hasSize(2);
    assertThat(
        paths.stream()
        .flatMap(
                graph -> graph.getEdgeList().stream()
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    ).containsExactly(newEdge("A", "B"), newEdge("B", "D"), newEdge("A", "C"), newEdge("C", "D"));
}

/**
 * it builds a basic graph containing these nodes:
 * 
 * <pre>
 *   -->B--
 *   |    |
 * A--    -->D
 *   |    |
 *   -->C--
 *   
 * </pre>
 * 
 * @return A directed graph containing four connected nodes
 */
private DirectedGraph<String, Edge> buildDirectedGraph() {
    DirectedGraph<String, Edge> directedGraph =
                                new DefaultDirectedGraph<String, Edge>(Edge.class);

    directedGraph.addVertex("A");
    directedGraph.addVertex("B");
    directedGraph.addVertex("C");
    directedGraph.addVertex("D");

    directedGraph.addEdge("A", "B");
    directedGraph.addEdge("A", "C");
    directedGraph.addEdge("B", "D");
    directedGraph.addEdge("C", "D");

    return directedGraph;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Dijkstra's Algorithm
[Refer Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

This is been used to find shortest path from one node to all the other nodes. But You can find Shortest path between 2 points using this algo.

Comment: I was specifically told not to use Dijkstra. I have to do it with BFS. If I could have used Dijkstra it would have been much simplier for me but now I'm struguling

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jfcorugedo answer, try to use `KShortestPaths` from the `JGraphT` library.

In my case, I had a graph with 25000 nodes and 250000 relationships and `KShortestPaths` just keeps running forever. In this case, if you can, I recommend you to use the [`NetworkX`](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.html) package for the Python language. It is the most complete graph library I found until now.

Take a look at the [`all_shortest_paths`](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html) function.